# display 2-3 lines if too long

Tags: split

i use datatool and connect Text and Image together.
See attached image.

If this text (Text A or Text B) is long, then split 2 lines.

Minimal Working code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextA,TextB
 1,a1 a1a1 a1a1a1 a1a1,b1 b1 b1
 2, ,b22 b2b2 b2b2b2 b2b2
 3,a3 a3 a3, b3b3
 4,,
 5,a5 a5a5,


\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


 \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=7cm,height=6cm]{name=A,column=1}{

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =-1em]
\item[]  \raisebox{1ex-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}  \TextA \hfill xxx
\item[]  \raisebox{1ex-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}  \TextB \hfill yyy
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with parbox as long as you are aware it cant split long words, your modified mwe does not compile as there are conflicting raisebox entries, so I have separated them for this amended answer

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextA,TextB
 1,a1 a1a1 a1a1a1 a1a1,b1 b1 b1 b1
 2, ,b22 b2b2 b2b2b2 b2b2
 3,a3 a3 a3, b3b3
 4,,
 5,a5 a5a5,


\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


 \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=7cm,height=6cm]{name=A,column=1}{

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =-1em]
\item[]  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\raisebox{-1ex}{~\parbox{3.5cm}{\raggedright \TextA \hfill ~ xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}}
\item[]  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\raisebox{-3pt}{~\parbox{3.5cm}{\raggedright \TextB \hfill ~ yyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank for your help. It's ok. But if i use raisebox{1ex-.5\height} instead \raisebox{-0.5\height) then break. Do you solution for raisebox{1ex-.5\height} thanks

Comment: Updated to include 2nd part raisebox + - ex or pt etc

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is use of `array`, `booktabs` and `adjustbox`  packages:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
No,TextA,TextB
1,a1 a1a1 a1a1a1 a1a1 aa aa aaaaaaaaaaa,b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1b1 b1 b1
2, ,b22 b2b2 b2b2b2 b2b2
3,a3 a3 a3, b3b3
4,,
5,a5 a5a5,
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*
{file}% Database
{\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
{%
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {
columns=1,
rows=1,
spacing=3mm,
height=14cm,
width=12cm,
},
]
%Box A
\posterbox[colframe=red,width=7cm,height=6cm]{name=A,column=1}%
{
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}} @{}}
\hline
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-a}
&   \centering\arraybackslash
    \TextA\ xxxx xx xxxxx              \\
\addlinespace
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-b}
&   \raggedright\arraybackslash
    \TextB\   yyyy yyy yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\newline
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, if long words are not natural, i.e. haven't \hyphenation points, that thew will spill out of table and `\posterbox` too..

Comment: Sorry but what is "\hyphenation" in code?

Comment: for the (almost) each language is defined option for this language for  `babel` option. It contain patterns for hyphenate of words  and other language specific definitions (as names of captions labels, etc).  However, this patterns cannot hyphenate words like `yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy` ...